# How to store all static media files of a website with heavy traffic?

Tags: load-balancing, distributed-filesystems, lvs

I heard of some distributed file systems like Gluster and Moose. Are there any better ideas out there that I am not aware of?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't mention this as a possibility, but how about a [CDN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network) like [Amazon CloudFront](http://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/), [Akamai](http://www.akamai.com/), [Limelight Networks](http://www.limelightnetworks.com/), or [Rackspace Cloud Files](http://www.rackspacecloud.com/cloud_hosting_products/files)?

Comment: I think I would not choose this service-like options. I need to build it on my own

Answer (score 0):

I use SQUID as a front-end proxy with caching rules setup for static content, so as that it's stored in RAM for common requests.  Unless you have a particular goal in mind as part of the backend architecture, I cannot see the need for a distributed file system.